# Vagrant up erroring out. invalid argument 'read' for box url

Tags: vagrant

I had a new developer start this morning, and Vagrant is erring out. It is unlike any Vagrant error I have seen before. Please help.

```
alex@Alexs-MacBook-Pro ~/Sites/hhlvh-box -  $ vagrant up

There were warnings and/or errors while loading your Vagrantfile

for the machine 'default'.



Your Vagrantfile was written for an earlier version of Vagrant,

and while Vagrant does the best it can to remain backwards

compatible, there are some cases where things have changed

significantly enough to warrant a message. These messages are

shown below.



Warnings:

* `config.vm.customize` calls are VirtualBox-specific. If you're

using any other provider, you'll have to use config.vm.provider in a

v2 configuration block.



Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...

==> default: Box 'hhlvh-box-v1.8.1' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...

    default: Box Provider: virtualbox

    default: Box Version: >= 0

/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/json/common.rb:328:in `read': Invalid argument - /Users/alex/Sites/hhlvh-box/debian7-hhlvh-v1.8.1.box (Errno::EINVAL)

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/json/common.rb:328:in `load'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/box_metadata.rb:24:in `initialize'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:448:in `new'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:448:in `block in metadata_url?'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:447:in `open'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:447:in `metadata_url?'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:72:in `block in call'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:70:in `map'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:70:in `call'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `block in run'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `run'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:75:in `handle_box'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:42:in `block in call'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:36:in `synchronize'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:36:in `call'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `block in run'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `run'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:51:in `call'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `block in run'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `run'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:157:in `action'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.0/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in run'
```

**Specs:**

- OSX Mavericks
- Virtualbox 4.3.8
- Vagrant 1.5

I thought it might have to do with his Vagrantfile, but when attempted to run `vagrant box add /Users/alex/Sites/hhlvh-box/debian7-hhlvh-v1.8.1.box` it resulted in the same error.

**Vagrantfile:**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hhlvh-box-v1.8.1"
  config.vm.box_url = "~/Sites/hhlvh-box/debian7-hhlvh-v1.8.1.box"
  config.vm.network :hostonly, "33.33.33.10"
  config.vm.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 2048]
  config.vm.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", 2]
  config.vm.share_folder "v-chef", "/chef-server", "~/Sites/chef-server", :nfs => true
  config.vm.share_folder "v-api", "/var/www/website.org/current", "~/Sites/api", :nfs => true
  config.vm.share_folder "v-webui", "/var/www/ui/current", "~/Sites/webui", :nfs => true
  config.ssh.username = "hhadmin"
end
```

Comment: could you post your Vagrantfile file?

Comment: @Rob3 Edited my original post

Comment: I think that there is a problem with the box's path. Try with the complete path..

Comment: Why do you not use Vagrant.Config version "2" ???

Answer (score 2):

I submitted a ticket via Vagrant's Github, and mitchellh says it is a problem with Vagrant v1.5 and will be fixed in v1.5.1. We resolved the issue by downloading v1.3.5, and it worked like a charm.

Cheers,
Jake

Comment: Link to issue: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3094, thanks for filing.